# alfresco's android sdk samples crashes when i enter the correct settings of the server

Tags: android, sdk, alfresco, sample

i am testing the sdk samples app from alfresco android sdk under a AVD, i am using alfresco community edition 4.2, when i enter a wrong Hostname i get the message "failed to log in. please check your settings", but when i enter the correct host name, the app crashes and i get the message "Unfortunately, SDK Samples has stopped." then it restarts...

there is this one time, i entered the correct host name and the app connected to the alfresco server without any problem, but when i tried a second time the problem persists

any idea what could be the problem?!!

LogCat

> 03-22 19:33:53.584: I/dalvikvm-heap(811): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.083MB for 108752-byte allocation
>   03-22 19:33:53.624: D/dalvikvm(811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 10% free 7153K/7879K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
>   03-22 19:33:53.814: D/dalvikvm(811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 9% free 7216K/7879K, paused 15ms+28ms, total 96ms
>   03-22 19:33:53.844: D/AndroidRuntime(811): Shutting down VM
>   03-22 19:33:53.844: W/dalvikvm(811): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.session.impl.RepositorySessionImpl.writeToParcel(RepositorySessionImpl.java:219)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6470)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1741)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1411)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at org.alfresco.mobile.android.samples.activity.SessionLoaderCallback.onLoadFinished(SessionLoaderCallback.java:191)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at org.alfresco.mobile.android.samples.activity.SessionLoaderCallback.onLoadFinished(SessionLoaderCallback.java:1)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:482)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:450)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at org.alfresco.mobile.android.api.asynchronous.AbstractBaseLoader.deliverResult(AbstractBaseLoader.java:65)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:254)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoAspectsImpl
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1013)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
>   03-22 19:33:53.894: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.cache.CacheImpl$CacheItem.writeObject(Cach
>   03-22 19:33:57.344: I/Process(811): Sending signal. PID: 811 SIG: 9
>   03-22 19:33:57.874: E/Trace(867): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   03-22 19:33:58.514: D/dalvikvm(867): GC_CONCURRENT freed 219K, 5% free 6215K/6535K, paused 16ms+4ms, total 80ms
>   03-22 19:33:58.564: I/Choreographer(867): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   03-22 19:33:58.574: D/gralloc_goldfish(867): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   03-22 19:33:58.695: I/Choreographer(867): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: The key line looks to be `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoAspectsImpl` - are you certain you have the latest Alfresco CMIS libs, and no older / mis-matched ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was due to a bug inside a dependency used by Alfresco Mobile SDK Sample.

This error has been fixed by the release of [alfresco-opencmis-extension 0.7-ANDROID](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.alfresco.cmis.client~alfresco-opencmis-extension~0.7-ANDROID~~) and in general by the release of Alfresco Mobile SDK 1.3.1.